# Allowance = Unlimited. What could happen?

Tags: ether, metamask, gas, etherscan, allowance

Allowance = Unlimited. What can happen?

Hi,

let‘s say I approve via MetaMask that another address can spend an unlimited amount of ETH on my address.

What can happen?
Can this address spend all my ETH without me approving it via my MetaMask?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Can this address spend all my ETH without me approving it via my MetaMask?

The `approve()` function is part of the [ERC-20 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20). Approving someone else's address gives them permission to transfer your ERC-20 tokens.

It does not grant permission over your ETH. Only the holder of the private key - which is hopefully only you - can move or spend your ETH.

So:

> let‘s say I approve via MetaMask that another address can spend an unlimited amount of ETH on my address.

That's not possible, without giving away your private key.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer. I'm too new to the system :D So let's say they have permission to transfer my ERC-20 tokens named ABC. Can they transfer all ABC tokens without my permission? Do they need the private key for this as well? If so, what can they do with just having the permission to transfer my ABC tokens but not having my private keys? I'm a bit confused..

Comment: _"Can they transfer all ABC tokens without my permission?"_ If you have approved an "infinite" (or very large) amount, then yes. You can remove your approval using a service such as https://approved.zone/ or https://etherscan.io/tokenapprovalchecker.

Comment: _"Do they need the private key for this as well?"_ No, just your approval, which they have.

Comment: _"If so, what can they do with just having the permission to transfer my ABC tokens but not having my private keys?"_ They can only transfer your ABC tokens to another address. They can't touch your ETH, nor any of your other tokens.

Comment: Thank you, Richard. Really well explained. That brings up the question: Why do I as a MetaMask user have to sign a swap?

Comment: This has to be done so that the Uniswap infrastructure - i.e. their contracts - can transfer the ERC-20 token on your behalf. When you swap tokens, it is using Uniswap as an intermediary - you're not swapping the with someone else directly.

Comment: Hm, I don't understand. If I give Uniswap an allowance to spend an unlimited amount of my ERC20-token ABC. Why do I still have to sign it again? Uniswap has my allowance.

Comment: Sorry - you mean when you click "Swap" and the Metamask pop-up pops up? In that case you're signing the transaction to prove (to the system as a whole, not just Uniswap) that it's you who's doing the swap. That transaction will then tell Uniswap to make the transfer/swap on your behalf. They are two different stages that both require your permission.

Comment: There have been discussions in the past about automatically carrying out the signing step if you've ticked some box to say it's okay, but I don't believe they've moved any closer to implementation -> https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/4011

Comment: I don't understand. I asked: "Can they transfer all ABC tokens without my permission?". You said: "If you have approved an "infinite" (or very large) amount, then yes.". Let's say I approved that Uniswap can spend an unlimited amount. Then that's this case.  Why do you say that I have to prove (to the system as a whole, not just Uniswap) that it's me who's doing the swap? You said that they can transfer all ABC ERC20 token without my permission.

Comment: Signing transactions (A) and token approvals (B) are two different things. Both are done via Metamask. (They can be done in other ways too, but Metamask is the easiest.)

Comment: Considering (A) first: Every time you send any transaction to the Ethereum network - whether that's to the Uniswap smart contract, or any other smart contract, or just to send ETH to another address - you have to sign the transaction to prove that it's your address which has sent it. Every time you make a swap on Uniswap you must sign the transaction that brings about that swap so that the rest of the network knows it's you. This allows the network as a whole to check that any changes made in the transaction are valid ones.

Comment: Uniswap does make the transfer on your behalf, but _you_ must send the transaction to start the chain of events.

Comment: (B): The first time you swap a token on Uniswap you have to make an approval of the ERC-20 to allow Uniswap to transfer it on your behalf. Every time you make a subsequent swap you don't have to re-make this approval - they can make transfers using the permission granted in the original approval. They _could_ maliciously drain your funds at any time they like once this approval has been made, _if_ their contract had been crafted to allow them to do that. It hasn't been written in that way (you can check - it's all open source), so people trust the code not to drain their funds.

Comment: Ah, that was an awesome explanation. Now I think I got it. Those if/then cases helped. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No problem - glad it helped! :-)